# Shunt resistor between differential lines before differential amp

Tags: resistors, noise, differential, esd, shunt

I wonder that why is the shunt resistor used between differential lines?

After I took a look the schematic of VR sensor interface, they suggest me to put shunt resistor. The shunt resistor can prevent the noise or is there a different reason?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/485284/filter-vr-sensor-to-max9926).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I looked at the question that you mentioned and I guess, as the value of shunt resistor increase, the noise from VR Sensor can reduce.

Answer (score 2):

The shunt is for impedance matching. Let's say you have RS 485 which requires 120 ohm load, a diff amp has a very high impedance - over 100k, so the impedance would not be matched. Adding in a 120 ohm shunt resistor matches the impedance.